# I still don't understand C++ operator new[] (or new[][])

Tags: c++, new-operator

I've typically shied away from *unnecessary* C++ *features* but as time marches on I can't avoid confronting my gremlins. Most recent of all is `operator new[]` and the potential for memory problems.

```
char *playerNewNames = new char[numPlayers][50];
```

It's great to know we don't need so many pointer `*` indirections and I'd feel confident in C iterating with `malloc` but the above seems a step too far. My compiler didn't complain but I want to be sure I will be getting an array of size `numPlayers` with each indexing a tranche of 50 characters. And how would I deallocate this?

I will try `delete[][]` but even if that doesn't throw it isn't 100% obvious that it will clean up everything, without iteration on my part. Please can somebody explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `new`. Use `std::array<T, N>` for constant-size arrays and `std::vector<T>` for dynamic ones. It's that simple.

Comment: I know char arrays are frowned on but I depend on a lot of legacy code that makes life much easier for me to continue to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new) Note: For your case, the comment to the question applies.

Comment: There are no `operator new[][]` and `operator delete[][]`. There are `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]` but you should not be using them. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Staying away from `new` is a great idea , keep doing it! Use containers which manage memory for you.

Comment: okay I do it iteratively as Xarn suggested. Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char *playerNewNames = new char[numPlayers][50];` is a mistake. You should get a compiler error. The correct syntax is:

```
char (*playerNewNames)[50] = new char[numPlayers][50];
```

and to delete it:

```
delete[] playerNewNames;
```

However a much better option would be to not use C-style arrays, and not use `new`. Instead, use container classes which manage the memory for you, such as `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: You are right about a compiler error, I hadn't synchronized my disk properly. `char (*playerNewNames)[50]` thanks, that was the code I was lacking :)

Answer (score 0):

The only proper way to deallocate an array is to use `delete[]`

`delete` deallocated single object while `delete[]` dealocates an array of objects.
there is no such thing as `delete[][]` or `delete[][][]`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want an array of arrays.

The most readable way, in my opinion, is to use a type alias.

```
typedef char PlayerName[50];

PlayerName* playerNewNames = new PlayerName[numPlayers];

delete [] playerNewNames;
```

If you want an array of pointers to arrays, you're going to need to iterate, but since you want all the "inner" arrays to have the same size, and it is known at compile time, that seems like a bad idea.

And learn about `std::vector` and `std::array`.